# AWS Lambda error { "errorType": "string", "errorMessage": "error", "trace": [] }, when send request on api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to build my first lambda function that triggered by an API gateway request, then sends to Queue service where I included down below: /when I send a request through api gateway, it gives status code: 200 but queue doesn't get any messages/

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    
    var params = {
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
        QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/********/****.fifo'
    };
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:', "Fail Send Message", +err);
            context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");
        } else {
            console.log('data:', data.MessageId);
            context.done(null, '');
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the CloudWatch logs of your Lambda function?

Comment: You are not using proxy integration for lambda. Are you sure this is a deliberate choice?

Comment: ``MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.``
@SarthakJain

Comment: Yes, for FIFO queues, you need to specify the MessageGroupId. You can specify a random id which matches the expected pattern - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property.